# How to Solve Too Much Load

Tags: android

I used **Volley** library in my apllication for RecyclerView on MainActivity but now when I run my application on android monitor there is saying `too much load on main thread`. An also main thread load slowly. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your application? Can you show us the relevant portions of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing small amount of dataset to recyclerview then I suggest you to run the method on [runOnUiThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/UiThreadTestRule.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

And if datasets are many(long executable code) then better make use of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: In this site before i searched was answered that volly library create a seperate thread without ui thread but now i don't know.

Comment: There's no need to combine volley  with AsyncTask. It does the networking  work on separate threads. Too much load on main thread occurs due to long executable codes (example like animation library which animates views inside OnCreate() method ) which causes some frames to be skipped and loads that activity slowly. Better to run those method on UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Long operations must be executed on the background thread, there are a lot of ways to achieve this : Loaders, Asynctask, handlers ,RXjava, etc.

Refer to this documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to let long operation task execute under worker threads. So UI thread will not suffer from these heavy payload.